# Dictionary of dictionaries: print dictionaries that share at least two common keys

Tags: python, dictionary, key, intersection

```
d = {'g1':{'p1':1,'p2':5,'p3':11,'p4':1},
     'g2':{'p1':7,'p3':1,'p4':2,'p5':8,'p9':11},
     'g3':{'p7':7,'p8':7},
     'g4':{'p8':9,'p9':1,'p10':7,'p11':8,'p12':3},
     'g5':{'p1':4,'p13':1},
     'g6':{'p1':4,'p3':1,'p6':2,'p13':1}
    }
```

For a given dictionary 'd' I want to return clusters of sub-dictionaries that share at least two ('n') keys (present in all sub-dictionaries of a given cluster). We don't care here about the values of these sub-dictionaries. In other words, length of the intersection of keys of all sub-dictionaries in a given cluster should be at least two (or 'n').

Comment: Homework? What have you tried?

Comment: Not a homework ;) I now how to do it in a for loop for pairs of keys, but have not idea how to make it globally - all against all.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood correctly what you want. The approach is clumsy and I fear it is highly inefficient.

I added a dictionary g6 to d in order to produce a more interesting output:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

d = {'g1':{'p1':1,'p2':5,'p3':11,'p4':1},
     'g2':{'p1':7,'p3':1,'p4':2,'p5':8,'p9':11},
     'g3':{'p7':7,'p8':7},
     'g4':{'p8':9,'p9':1,'p10':7,'p11':8,'p12':3},
     'g5':{'p1':4,'p13':1},
     'g6':{'p1':1,'p9':2,'p11':12}
    }

clusters = {}

for key, value in d.items ():
    cluster = frozenset (value.keys () )
    if cluster not in clusters: clusters [cluster] = set ()
    clusters [cluster].add (key)


for a in clusters.keys ():
    for b in clusters.keys ():
        if len (a & b) > 1 and a ^ b:
            cluster = frozenset (a & b)
            if cluster not in clusters: clusters [cluster] = set ()
            for x in clusters [a]: clusters [cluster].add (x)
            for x in clusters [b]: clusters [cluster].add (x)

print "Primitive clusters"
for key, value in filter (lambda (x, y): len (y) == 1, clusters.items () ):
    print "The dictionary %s has the keys %s" % (value.pop (), ", ".join (key) )

print "---------------------"
print "Non-primitive clusters:"
for key, value in filter (lambda (x, y): len (y) > 1, clusters.items () ):
    print "The dictionaries %s share the keys %s" % (", ".join (value), ", ".join (key) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
for keya in d:
    tempd = {}
    keys = set()
    tempset = set(d[keya].keys())

    for keyb in d:
        tempset &= d[keyb].keys()

        if len(tempset) >= 2:
            keys.add(keyb)

    print({key: d[key] for key in keys})
```

Might work.

EDIT: No it doesn't quite work. I'll need to think about this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first 'invert' the dictionary and then finding the solution is easy:

```
import collections
inverted = collections.defaultdict(list)

for key, items in d.items():
    for sub_key in items:
        inverted[sub_key].append(key)

for sub_key, keys in inverted.items():
    if len(keys) >= 2:
        print sub_key, keys
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simplify the problem to only clusters of length 2 (ie, pairs of dictionaries) it becomes slightly clearer: generating fixed-length subsequences from a given iterable is exactly the job of itertools.combinations:

```
>>> list(itertools.combinations(d, 2))
[('g5', 'g4'), ('g5', 'g3'), ('g5', 'g2'), ('g5', 'g1'), ('g4', 'g3'), ('g4', 'g
2'), ('g4', 'g1'), ('g3', 'g2'), ('g3', 'g1'), ('g2', 'g1')]
```

We can see the number of keys any dictionaries have in common by realising that the view d.keys() behaves like a set (in Python 3; in Python 2, it may be a list):

```
>>> d['g1'].keys() & d['g2'].keys()
{'p3', 'p1', 'p4'}
```

& is the set intersection operator - it gives us the set of all items these sets have in common. We can therefore check that there are atleast two of these by checking the length of this set, which gives us:

```
>>> common_pairs = [[x,y] for x,y in itertools.combinations(d, 2)
                                   if len(d[x].keys() & d[y].keys()) >= 2]
>>> common_pairs
[['g2', 'g1']]
```

Solving for an unknown cluster size is slightly harder - we can't use the & operator directly if we aren't hardcoding this. Thankfully, the set class provides us with a method to take the intersection of *n* sets in the form of set.intersection. It won't accept a dict_keys instance, but you can easily fix that with a call to set:

```
>>> set.intersection(d['g1'].keys(), d['g2'].keys(), d['g5'].keys())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor 'intersection' requires a 'set' object but received a 'dict_keys'
>>> set.intersection(set(d['g1']), set(d['g1']), set(d['g5']))
{'p1'}
```

You should be able to generalise this to the clusters of size 2 through *n* fairly trivially.